# Greedy algorithm - Out of idea

Tags: java, arraylist, jpanel

I'm making a "Ribbon Packing" personal project, and I am stuck.

I have `N` random size blocks. I need to put all of the N blocks inside the ribbon, to have the smallest height as possible.

[This is the visual result I currently get (without the part of the `else`)](https://puu.sh/ChuwW/1838ab8c5d.png).

Everything is working for the first line into the ribbon, the problem is when it need to print other blocks on top of the blocks already in the ribbon. I tried several things but still nothing (i'll put the last "version" below).

```
public void algoGlouton(Graphics g) {

    ArrayList<Bloc> listBlocRemaining = (ArrayList<Bloc>) blocksList.clone(); 

    int offsetX = 13;
    int offsetY = 600;
    int widthAvailable= 0;
    int smallestHeight= 300;

    for (Bloc b : blocksList.clone) {
        if(widthRemaining + b.getWidth () < ribbon.getWidth ()) {
            widthAvailable += b.getWidth();

            g.setColor(b.getColor());
            g.fillRect(offsetX, offsetY - b.getHeight(), b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());
            listBlocksIntoRibbon.add(b);

            b.setX(offsetX);
            b.setY(offsetY - b.getHauteur());
            offsetX += b.getLargeur();

        } else { //Below is the mess
            // We search the smallest height
            for (Bloc b1 : listBlocksIntoRibbon) {
                if (b1.getHauteur() < smallestHeight) {
                    //when we have the smallest, we go through the blocks remaining
                    for (Bloc b2 : listBlocRemaining) {
                        // PlaceRemaining is an int into the block class and its equal to his width
                        // we see if the block can fit above the smallest height
                        if (b1.getPlaceRemaining() > b2.getWidth()){
                            b2.setX(b1.getX());
                            b2.setY(b1.getHeight() - b2.getHeight());

                            g.setColor(b.getColor());
                            g.fillRect(b1.getX(), b1.getHeight() - b2.getHeight(), b2.getWidth(), b2.getHeight());              
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm really lost right now, I did my best to resolve this, but I need some help to go further.

Comment: No one can help me ?

Comment: "the problem is when it need to print other blocks" - what kind of problem do you experience? An exception? Overlapping blocks? Sub-optimal placement? And a hint on design: never mix algorithms and input/output, place these aspects at least in different methods.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. [This is what I have with this code](https://puu.sh/ChvNV/c339bd11a4.png) . There is a huge probleme as you can see, I'm on it since hours, and still no clue.. The input are the `fillrect` ?

Comment: Ok, I see. I can only recommend to use your IDE's debugger and single-step through your program, watching the values of your variables. Then most probably you'll find a place where a variable has a value that you didn't expect. And that will build up your programming and debugging skills, so I won't do that for you.

Comment: I did debug, It was a `b2.setY(b1.getY() - b2.getHeight());` instead of `b2.setY(b1.getHeight() - b2.getHeight());` Now, [I have this](https://puu.sh/Chwvs/34f900aca5.png) I'm going to try to resolve this problem.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Thumbs up!

Comment: Well, I guess I need to change how I put blocks on top of blocks. As you can see in my previous comment, there is some little white blank between the blocks. And thats not good if we want an minimal height. So, I was thinking of something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs37U.png) I need to save each of this red x/y and check after if I can put a block on it, do you understand me ?